# Deleting and editing specific structs in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

My content view is a form populated by a decoded json array like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var bookData: [Book] = load("list")
    @State private var selectedBook: Book? = nil
    @State private var active = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
                Form {
                    ForEach(bookData){ bookDetail in
                        BookView(book: bookDetail)
                            .background(
                                NavigationLink(destination: EditBook(bookData: $bookData, book: bookDetail), tag: bookDetail, selection: $selectedBook) {
                                           EmptyView()
                                        }
                                    )
                            .contextMenu{
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                    //delete action here

                                }) {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")

                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Books")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: NewBook(bookData: $bookData)){Image(systemName: "plus.circle").font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)})
        }
    }

}
```

The way my app works right now is that the NewBook and Edit book views have a binder property to my bookData array. To add new book to the array the NewBook view just appends bookData with another struct and encodes it with writeJSON(bookData). Similarly in content view I want to remove a element using a context menu and reencode the edited array. For the editBook view I want to edit a struct and use writeJSON to encode it.

Here is my editBook view:

```swift
struct EditBook: View {

    @Binding var bookData: [Book]
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    @State private var page = ""
    @State private var total = ""
    
    var book: Book
    
    var body: some View {
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Change the details of the book")){
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Name:")
                        TextField(book.name, text: $name)
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Author:")
                        TextField(book.author, text: $author)
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Page number:")
                        TextField(book.page, text: $page)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Number of pages:")
                        TextField(book.total, text: $total)
                            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    }
                }
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Update book")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Book")
    }
}
```

and here is the NewBook view that works (for reference)

```swift
struct NewBook: View {
    @Binding var bookData: [Book]
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    @State private var page = ""
    @State private var total = ""
    
    var body: some View {
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("Enter the details of the book")){
                    TextField("Title", text: $name)
                    TextField("Author", text: $author)
                    TextField("Current page number", text: $page)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                    TextField("Total number of pages", text: $total)
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                }
                
                Section{
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            bookData.append(Book(id: UUID(), name: name, author: author, page: page, total: total, image: "string"))
                            writeJSON(bookData)
                        }) {
                            Text("Add book")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("New Book")
    }
}
```

I tried using `bookData.removeAll(where: {bookData.contains(bookDetail)})` in the content view but that deleted everything.

Comment: I would start by refactoring to use a model object. This object should contain your book array as well as handling serialisation/deserialisation. You can Lao have your book conform to `identifiable` (Or at least have a unique identifier) so that your model can easily identify which book is being edited

Comment: @Paulw11 The book struct already conforms to identifiable with a uuid, I don’t get why I should make the array into a struct (the only reason I can think of is so that the struct contains my encode and decode function)

Comment: Exactly. Encoding and decoding and other business logic belongs in your model, not in your view. In fact I would probably make it a class rather than a struct.

Comment: @Paulw11 would that improve performance, what's the benefit?

Comment: It's not about performance. It's about architecture. By using a model object that is a class you get mutability, reference semantics and ObservableObject support. In SwiftUI you should have little to no procedural code in your views

Comment: Okay but my functions lie in a separate swift file, isn't that a similar solution?

Comment: Well you are calling `writeJson(someArray)`, not `someModel.writeJSON()` so you aren't using object oriented techniques. It seems that you just have some global functions sitting out there somewhere.  If you use appropriate OO design then you wouldn't even have `JSON` in the function name. The view code should not know or care how the data is persisted. It could be json, it could be core data, it could be sql... in fact your view shouldn't even need to call a `write` function at all. Add a book to the model and let it take care of things like persistence.

Comment: I have added an example project to Git showing how I would approach this sort of app - https://github.com/paulw11/BookApp. You will see how there is essentially an abstract `Library` class which I subclass to a `MockLibrary` for content previewing and a `JSONLibrary` that persists to a local JSON file.  You can see how it would be easy tho create a `CoreDataLibrary` that used Core Data and none of the SwiftUI views would need to change.  Encapsulation also makes unit testing easy - I created unit tests for the base `Library`

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you so much, this is great reference for the future, however its a little too advanced for me right now and I am trying to build this app myself as far as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some trial and error, here is what works for me.

To delete a element I put this code in the button of content view

```swift
bookData.removeAll(where: { $0.id == bookDetail.id })
writeJSON(bookData)
```

and for editing the data I did this

```swift
let id = book.id
bookData.removeAll(where: { $0.id == book.id })
let temp = Book(id: id, name: name, author: author, page: page, total: total, image: "Image")
bookData.insert(temp, at: 0)
writeJSON(bookData)
```

Note how the id remains the same for the edit.